# PyQt5 MYSQL driver not loaded windows

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt5

I am having this issue when I am trying to connect to a local mysql database using QSqlDatabase.addDatabase() method.

I know there are several similar questions posted, but they offer no clear solutions especially as most of them as for C++, and they assumed we can the Qt documentation which I can't

Specifically I'd like to know which are missing files (.dll, .so, .lib)? where do I get them? and where do I copy them? in case for Python not C++

This is error I get when try to run my python script:

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7
```

I am using Windows 10, MySql 8, Python 3.6, PyQt 5.9 and PyQt-tools 5.9 (I am using this version of PyQt because I am also using fbs, the fbs manual says it works better with that version of PyQt5 and Python)

This is a useful statement that I read in stackoverflow but it is for C++:
"""
Remember that qsqlmysql plugin is basically a qt interface that uses mysql-C connector methods. But unfortunately this connector does not distributed with Qt, so you should provide it by yourself.
"""

So as I said before the important thing is to know which are missing files (.dll, .so, .lib)? where do I get them? and where do I copy them?

Please let me know if you need my script, but it's a very simple one:

1. I try to connect using QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QMYSQL')
2. Instantiate a QSqlTableModel that uses that db connection and sets a single table of that database.
3. Display this single table in a QTableView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using "QMYSQL3" as:

```
db= QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL3")
db.setHostName('host_name')
db.setUserName('user_name')
db.setDatabaseName('database')
db.setPassword('password')
ok = db.open()
if ok:
    print('Success')
else:
    print(db.lastError().text())
```

If your problem is not solved you may check that your libmysql.dll file is not in your python executable folder, and if so, copy the file from the python 3.x/lib/site-packages to your python 3.xx executable folder. It worked for me.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked by copying the file in my environment folder where the python executable is